# Future tense to express possibility in the present

Tags: futuro

I was reading through my old *501 Spanish verbs* book and it says that the future tense can be used to express possibility in the present. i.e. "María estará enferma." would translate to "María is probably sick.".

I'm confused as to how I would use the future tense to say, "*María will become sick*". Are you forced into using the verb ir in this case? "*María va a estar enferma*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Manual de la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* refers under item 23.7.2 to the "futuro de conjetura". It is neither unusual nor restricted to the interrogative form. The bolds are mine:

> 23.7.2a Se llama FUTURO DE CONJETURA, FUTURO DE PROBABILIDAD o FUTURO EPISTÉMICO el que introduce alguna **suposición del hablante relativa al presente**. [...] ***Serán** las ocho* significa aproximadamente (en uno de sus sentidos) "Probablemente son las ocho" o "Deben de ser las ocho".

Other examples that appear in the same section are:

- Ahora **estará** en las Bahamas.
- Le **parecerá** una tontería, pero aquello me salvó de morir.
- ¿Dónde **estará** Marta?
- ¿Qué **querrá** ahora?
- ¿**Estará** loco?
- Me imagino que **estará** muy ocupado.
- Comprendo que **estará** usted molesto.

In English, we do have a similar use, albeit not so extended as in Spanish, at least in the simple form:

A. Somebody rang the bell. Who will it be?
B. It will be the postman. (Tocaron el timbre. ¿Quién será? / Será el cartero.)

This future of probability also exists in the continuous and perfect forms:

- ¿Qué estará haciendo? / Estará durmiendo. (He must be sleeping.)
- No lo veo. Se habrá quedado dormido. (He must have overslept.)

Answer (score 2):

Para expresar posibilidad en el presente se utiliza el modo subjuntivo.

> To express possibility in the present, the subjunctive mood is used.

El modo subjuntivo es un modo gramatical especial y a veces difícil de usar que habitualmente se utiliza para expresar hipótesis, afirmaciones inciertas, probabilidades o deseos.

> The subjunctive mood is a special and sometimes difficult to use
> grammatical mood that is commonly used to express hypotheses,
> uncertain statements, probabilities, or wishes.

Para expresar la idea de "María estará enferma" debe de estar en un contexto.

> To express the idea of "María estará enferma" it must be in a context.

En este contexto podemos utilizar el subjuntivo o el indicativo utilizado como probabilidad, pero lo más frecuente es usar el subjuntivo ya que el futuro de indicativo "estará" puede sonar raro en algunas zonas.

> In this context we can use the subjunctive or the indicative used as a
> probability, but the most common is to use the subjunctive since the
> future indicative "will be" can sound strange in some areas.

- María probablemente **esté** enferma. (María estará enferma), (María probablemente estará enferma).

Contexto

> Context

- A - María no ha venido hoy al colegio.
- B - María probablemente esté enferma. (Quizás una razón de que María no haya venido hoy a clase es que ella esté enferma), (estuviere enferma), (esta enferma), (es que ella (probablemente si no ha venido) estará enferma), (estará entonces enferma), (estará enferma).

Answer (score -1):

Future tense to imply a possibility is most often used while in interrogative mode, or asking a question:

> ¿Estará enferma María? no la hemos visto últimamente
> *Is Maria sick? we haven't seen her lately*

or

> ¿Ganará Argentina la copa del mundo?
> *Will Argentina win the world cup?*

Comment: Also: of course, Argentina did win the world cup, but that is a phrase you'd be very likely to have seen lately